# SQL query that returns all the ids without a certain value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that maps User and Feature. Basically what features are enabled for each user. The table is |userId|featureId| with one(user) to many(feature) relationship.

I would like to create a query that takes a list of userIds and returns the list of userIds that are **missing** a specific feature.

Meaning I need to make sure that every id has a specific featureId.

```
userId  featureId
1       A
1       B
2       A
3       C
4       D
3       A
```

So in this example, I'll get the list of ids (1, 2, 3, 4) and a featureId A and the query will return one row with userId 4 since it's the only userId with the feature A enabled.

Comment: Where's the list of all features?  In theory there could be a feature for which no user has an association correct?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Post your query.

Comment: Why not user 1 c,d user 2 b,c,d user 3 b,d user 4 a,b,c?  How do we know it's A we're after?   The issue is just because 3 of the 4 users have A how do we know that's the one we want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find a list of users that don't have feature X I would left join to the list of users that has that feature and return the ones not there.  Like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_you_did_not_name as base
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT userID
  FROM table_you_did_not_name
  WHERE feature = 'X'
) as sub ON base.userID = sub.userID
WHERE sub.userID is null
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I may have answered a different question: this doesn't address your data; but I'm unsure how you determine it is user 4 you want returned. as each user is missing some of the features the others have.  Perhaps we just need to add a where clause below for the specific feature(A) in your example?

Think of data in terms of sets

You need

1. a set of data for all users (User or something)
2. a set of data for all features (feature)
3. and what features a user has (User_Feature)

Then you need to

1. Generate a set of every feature to every users (cross join)
2. Identify which of those the user has identified. (left join in user_feature)
3. and then only keep those where no feature has been identified (where no record in user_feature)

One method: This basically says return the features for each user that exist in a feature list, but have not been associated to a user.

```
SELECT U.userID, F.FeatureID as FeatureIDMissing
FROM USER U
CROSS JOIN FEATURE F
LEFT JOIN UserFeature UF
 on U.UserID = UF.UserID
and F.FeatureID = UF.FeatureID
WHERE UF.UserID is null
--  and F.FeatureID = 'A' --maybe add this?
```

Alternate method: (combine two steps (2,3) by simply excluding those features which already exist for the user.

In english this says, return all the features for each user for which a user has not been associated

```
SELECT U.userID, F.FeatureID as FeatureIDMissing
FROM USER U
CROSS JOIN FEATURE F
WHERE not exists (SELECT *
                  FROM userFeature UF
                  WHERE U.UserID = UF.UserID
                    and F.FeatureID = UF.FeatureID)
--and F.FeatureID = 'A' --maybe add this?
```

Either answer should return the same results.  It's a matter of preference database and performance .. Look at the execution plans to help decide which is best for you and your data.

Now maybe you mean you give a list of userID's you want to generate a unique set of features for all those users, and then return users w/o those features.  If so instead of a cross join to feature you just need to use `(Select distinct FeatureID from userFeatures where UserID IN ('yourListHere')`  this will generate a unique set of features for those users and identify which users are missing certain features shared with that set of users.

So...

```
SELECT U.userID, F.FeatureID as FeatureIDMissing
FROM USER U
CROSS JOIN (SELECT distinct FeatureID 
            FROM userFeatures 
            WHERE UserID IN ('yourListHere')F
LEFT JOIN UserFeature UF
 on U.UserID = UF.UserID
and F.FeatureID = UF.FeatureID
WHERE UF.UserID is null
--  and F.FeatureID = 'A' --maybe add this?
```

as an example.